# Remove Badge from tabbar item

Tags: iphone

How to Remove Badge from the tabbar item i had use below code but not working for me.

```
UITabBarItem *chatbadge=[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
chatbadge.badgeValue=nil;
```

Suggest any Solution.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try doing it via the viewController:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];

viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift version & this is really weird

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[3].tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
```

is working and not

```
self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
```

Comment: This seems to have been fixed.  ```self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil``` working fine on Swift 5